# How to use where and skip in same condition for Laravel queries?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a news website and in a partial i must skip first 5 headline articles and fetch others.

There are 2 parts on my page. One is slider ( for headline posts ) and second is for other posts ( non-headline articles and headline articles after last 5 )

My query is not working. I think i need two conditions on my where query.
skip where is headline and last 5 posts..

This query does not work :

```
 ->where('headline', '=', '1')->take(15)->skip(5)->get();
```

When i use this query , it also skip my non-headline posts in last 5 posts. But i want to show them.

How can i achieve this ?

Comment: Did you add ```->get()``` to the end?

Comment: yes , of course

Comment: What does `->where('headline', '=', '1')->skip(5)->toSql()` gives you

Comment: Method toSql does not exist. :)

Comment: Try exchanging the skip and take methods: `->where('headline', '=', '1')->skip(5)->take(15)->get();`

Comment: If you want to show non-headline posts then remove your where clause. It is only going to show headline posts by the looks of it.

Comment: no , i want to show headlines also but not all. headline post after last 5.

Comment: Gaurav no it does not work

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to show two sets:

1. Headlined posts (5x)
2. All posts, except first 5 headlined posts

so:

```
$headliners = Post::where('headline', '=', '1')->take(5)->get();

$regulars = Post::whereNotIn('id', $headliners->pluck('id'))->get();
```